# How can I populate a heat template in OpenStack with `user_data` without including the script inline?

Tags: openstack

I.e. I want my template to look something like:

```
...
resources:
  server1:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: Server1
      image: { get_param: image }
      flavor: { get_param: flavor }
      user_data: ?????
...
```

and I want the contents of user_data to be stored in a separate file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Pass it in as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's what [get_file](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/hot_spec.html#get-file) is for. From the doc:

> The example below demonstrates get_file usage with both relative and
>   absolute URLs.
>
> ```
> resources:
>   my_instance:
>     type: OS::Nova::Server
>     properties:
>       # general properties ...
>       user_data:
>         get_file: my_instance_user_data.sh
>   my_other_instance:
>     type: OS::Nova::Server
>     properties:
>       # general properties ...
>       user_data:
>         get_file: http://example.com/my_other_instance_user_data.sh
> ```
>
> If this template was launched from a local file this would result in a
>   files dictionary containing entries with keys
>   file:///path/to/my_instance_user_data.sh and
>   http://example.com/my_other_instance_user_data.sh.