# Openstack (devstack) Heat template to create vm and app on it

Tags: ubuntu, ant, openstack, devstack, openstack-heat

Is it possible, using  heat template, create VM instance (eg:. ubuntu) and install on it some application? I want create ubuntu instance and install on it apache ant using  heat template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the user_data section of the Server resource to specify a script that installs software.

```
buildslave:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      ..
      ..
      user_data: |
           #!/bin/bash -v
           apt-get update
           apt-get install ant
```

The script can also be external to the Heat template:

- [How can I populate a heat template in OpenStack with `user_data` without including the script inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124221/how-can-i-populate-a-heat-template-in-openstack-with-user-data-without-includi)